# JQuery HTML form validation still triggers email with blank entries

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have an HTML form with three mandatory fields in. I don't want the form to submit the AJAX call if they are empty.

```
$("#contact").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var ajaxurl = '<?php echo WEB_URL; ?>contact_send.php';
    var data = $(this).serializeArray();
    console.log(data);
        var valid = true;
        if( $('input[name="Name"]').val() == '' || $('input[name="Email"]').val() == '' || $('input[name="Phone"]').val() == '') {
            valid = false;
        }
        if(valid) {
            $.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {
               $(".show_homecontact_form_success").fadeIn(1000);
                $("#contact")[0].reset();
            });
        } else {
            alert('Please fill in all mandatory fields.');
        }
});

<form id="contact" name="contact" method="post" action="">
<label for="Name">Name: *</label>
<input type="text" name="Name" id="name" />
<input name="robotest" type="hidden" value="" />
<label for="Position">Position:</label>
<input type="text" name="Position" id="position" />
<label for="Company">Company:</label>
<input type="text" name="Company" id="company" />
<label for="Address">Address:</label>
<input type="text" name="Address" id="address" />
<label for="Email">Email: *</label>
<input type="text" name="Email" id="email" />
<label for="Email">Phone number: *</label>
<input type="text" name="Phone" id="phone" />
<label for="Event_Subject">What is the subject of the event?:</label>
<input type="text" name="Event_Subject" id="subject" />
<label for="Event_Date">What is the date of the event?:</label>
<input type="text" name="Event_Date" id="date" />
<label for="Additional_info">Additional Information:</label>
<br />
<textarea name="Additional_info" rows="20" cols="20" id="info"></textarea>
<input id="formsubmitted" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="submit-button" />
</form>
```

This does give the popup box if you try and fill it in empty, but I have received an email with all blank fields.

How is the user getting past the validation and managing to send the form through blank?

Comment: Show us your HTML code?

Comment: Just added to the original post.

Comment: Is that all you have on the page? Could there be another element with the id `contact` on the page?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#contact").submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var ajaxurl = '<?php echo WEB_URL; ?>contact_send.php';
  var data = $(this).serializeArray();
  console.log(data);
      var valid;
      if( $('input[name="Name"]').val().length > 0
              && $('input[name="Email"]').val().length > 0
              && $('input[name="Phone"]').val().length > 0) {
          valid = true;
      } else {
          valid = false;
      }
      if(valid) {
          $.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {
             $(".show_homecontact_form_success").fadeIn(1000);
              $("#contact")[0].reset();
          });
      } else {
          alert('Please fill in all mandatory fields.');
      }
});
```

As *Jigar* pointed out, you can shorten the code by assigning an initial value to the *valid* variable and removing *else* block:

```
var valid = false;
if( $('input[name="Name"]').val().length > 0
            && $('input[name="Email"]').val().length > 0
            && $('input[name="Phone"]').val().length > 0) {
      valid = true;
}
```

Comment: nothing wrong, but put `var valid = false;` and remove `else` part. less code :)

Answer (score 0):

More than likely you've not popped in a preventDefault() in there, so the form is doing a normal (non-AJAX) post after your function ends.  What's the method/action on your form?  Perhaps there doesn't need to be an action at all?

Comment: e.preventDefault();